# How do I get a count of results from a query?

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

I need help on a query, or a link to an answer that covers it:

I have two tables: `STOCK_ITEMS` and `STOCK_LOC_INFO`

`STOCK_ITEMS` has many fields, but the two of interest are `STOCKCODE` and `STOCK_CLASSIFICATION`

`STOCK_LOC_INFO` contains a record for every stock location (11 locations) against every `STOCKCODE`

`STOCK_ITEMS`:

```
 item1,class 1
 item2,class 2
 item3,class 1
```

`STOCK_LOC_INFO`

```
item1,location1,qty1
item1,location2,qty2
item1,location3,qty3
```

etc, repeating the 11 rows for each stock code.

NOW...
I want to find how many stockcodes of a certain class are in stock (qty is more than 0) across 5 of the 11 locations. I tried this:

```
select COUNT(SOH.STOCKCODE)
from dbo.STOCK_ITEMS SOH
Inner join STOCK_LOC_INFO SLI
on SOH.STOCKCODE = SLI.STOCKCODE
where SLI.QTY > 0 and SLI.LOCATION in(1,2,3,9,11)
```

and got a result of 9790 - which is far too high (expected about 900) because it's counting each time the required partnumber appears in the Stock Loc table with more than 0...but I want only a yes or no for each stockcode, not each qty.

I suspect it needs a COUNTIF or similar. I am just so lost!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Specify and/or tag your specific DBMS of choice. Questions like this vary greatly depending on whether you use MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite etc. etc.

Comment: Is stockcode the identifier for stock_items?  What RDBMS? Which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Oracle you could do like this:

```
select COUNT(SOH.STOCKCODE)
  from dbo.STOCK_ITEMS SOH
 WHERE SOH.STOCKCODE IN (
              SELECT SLI.STOCKCODE
                FROM STOCK_LOC_INFO SLI
               where SLI.QTY > 0 
                 and SLI.LOCATION in(1,2,3,9,11)
                       )
```

Comment: Yay! I just had to add `and SOH.CLASS = '[class no]' ` and it works mint!

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want the count of distinct stockcodes that meet your criteria?
If so:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SOH.STOCKCODE)
FROM STOCK_ITEMS SOH
INNER JOIN STOCK_LOC_INFO SLI
ON SOH.STOCKCODE = SLI.STOCKCODE
WHERE SLI.QTY > 0 AND SLI.LOCATION IN(1,2,3,9,11)
```

You could also limit the SLI table before joining:

```
SELECT COUNT(SOH.STOCKCODE)
FROM STOCK_ITEMS SOH
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT STOCKCODE 
            FROM STOCK_LOC_INFO
            WHERE QTY > 0 AND LOCATION IN(1,2,3,9,11)
            )SLI
ON SOH.STOCKCODE = SLI.STOCKCODE
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (  SELECT SOH.STOCKCODE, COUNT(*) AS N
        FROM dbo.STOCK_ITEMS SOH
        INNER JOIN STOCK_LOC_INFO SLI
            ON SOH.STOCKCODE = SLI.STOCKCODE
        WHERE SLI.QTY > 0 AND SLI.LOCATION in(1,2,3,9,11)
        GROUP BY SOH.STOCKCODE
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 5) A
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select count(1)
from dbo.STOCK_ITEMS SOH
inner join (select distinct STOCKCODE, LOCATION
             from STOCK_LOC_INFO
             where QTY > 0 and LOCATION in(1,2,3,9,11)) SLI
on SOH.STOCKCODE = SLI.STOCKCODE
```

It counts total number of unique STOCKCODEs with QTY>0 in each selected location.

Comment: That gives me the same answer as I got: 9790.